# Conditions of $AB=0$ where $A$ and $B$ are matrices of compatible dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n\times m$ matrix and $B$ an $m \times k$ matrix. Show that $AB = 0$
if and only if $\operatorname{Col}(B) \subseteq \operatorname{Nul}(A)$.
Here, $\operatorname{Col}$ denotes the column space and $\operatorname{Nul}$ denotes the null space.

I started off by writing down what I know,

Let v ∈ Col($B$), then $B$v=$x$ for some vector x

Let u ∈ Nul($A$), then $A$u=$0$

I then went to consider,

($AB=0$)v "Implies" ($AB$)v=$0$

but that's where it all got messed up. Does anyone know how to do it? Was I going down the right track?

Comment: Please read and heed [this meta thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351).

Comment: Some parts of this problem are straightforward, and if you are stumbling on those aspects, it surely must be remedied by understanding definitions.  Only then can you benefit from a discussion of proving the converse.

Comment: If $v$ is in the column space, then it's a linear combination of the columns: $Bx=v$ for some vector $x$. This is different from $Bv=0$ (which is not true in general for vectors in the column space; if the matrices aren't square, you can't even multiply your matrix by an element of the column space).

Answer (score 2):

Let the columns of $B$ be denoted by $b_{1},b_{2},...,b_{k}$

We can write $B$ as the list of columns $[b_{1},b_{2},...,b_{k}]$

We know that $AB = 0$

Because $(AB)_{ij}$ = $A_{i}.B_{j}$ we can write the product $AB=0$ as $[Ab_{1},Ab_{2},Ab_{3},...,Ab_{k}]=0$

So evidently $Ab_{1} = Ab_{2} =...= Ab_{k} = 0$ since all entries of the $0$ matrix are $0$

So thus all $b$ in $Col(B)$ must be contained in $Nul(A)$